# USB 3.0 host controller suddenly stopped working

Tags: usb, hardware

```
sudo lshw
        *-usb:0 UNCLAIMED
             description: USB controller
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:f7120000-f712ffff
```

Only the two USB 2.0 controllers function properly:

```
sw3@pc90313-sw3:~$ ls /dev/bus/usb
001  002
```

The 3.0 controller was listed as `004`, but now it's suddenly gone.

```
sw3@pc90313-sw3:~$ dmesg | grep USB
[    0.156319] ACPI: bus type USB registered
[    0.459505] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    0.459593] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    0.472274] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    0.472286] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    0.472287] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.472355] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.472493] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    0.488286] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    0.488293] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    0.488294] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.488364] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.488449] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    0.488453] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    0.488543] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
[    0.784538] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    0.916941] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0024
[    0.916943] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    0.917078] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.188920] usb 1-1.1: new low-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[    1.285374] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c05a
[    1.285375] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    1.285376] usb 1-1.1: Product: USB Optical Mouse
[    1.357061] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[    1.451516] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1366, idProduct=0101
[    1.451517] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    1.521200] usb 1-1.3: new low-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[    1.619030] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c31c
[    1.619031] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    1.619032] usb 1-1.3: Product: USB Keyboard
[   25.307285] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: USB bus 3 deregistered
[   25.358978] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[   25.362327] input: Logitech USB Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/input/input2
[   25.362388] hid-generic 0003:046D:C05A.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.1/input0
[   25.362469] input: Logitech USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/input/input3
[   25.362517] hid-generic 0003:046D:C31C.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Logitech USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.3/input0
[   25.364344] input: Logitech USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.1/input/input4
[   25.364394] hid-generic 0003:046D:C31C.0003: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Device [Logitech USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.3/input1
[   25.517596] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[   25.650056] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0024
[   25.650058] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[   25.650208] hub 2-1:1.0: USB hub found
```

What could be going on?

```
sw3@pc90313-sw3:~$ uname -a
Linux pc90313-sw3 3.11.0-13-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 23 07:38:26 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Even the newest kernel still seems to have serious problems with some USB3 controllers :(

Answer (score 1):

This was a very strange situation.

My PC is dual-boot with a Windows7. I had logged into windows for a short while, and while shutting it off, it began installing updates.

Next I logged in Ubuntu and the described problems occurred.

Going back to Windows for it to finish updating (at boot time), and then back to Linux solved the problem.

I am still wondering how did windows manage to mis-configure the very hardware.

The issue's gone now.